# IS there any way to enable 3G connection in IPhone Programmatically

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to programatically start 3g connection on iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217945/how-to-programatically-start-3g-connection-on-iphone)

I need to connect to 3G  connection Programmatically  ,  If Suppose i clicked a UIButton

then 3G connection should enable and disable every time . is this possible if possible how.

please help me.

Thanks,
Nikss

Comment: thanks for the reply , One more Thing if my iPhone is connected to wi-fi , and i download some data at that time it should use 3G network for downloading the data even if wi-fi is enable is this possible..

Comment: No, as a developer you have no right to download data over a user's 3G network without their knowledge (Which if an API existed, it would allow)