# iOS Development Wifi-Call

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi, call

I am working as a programmer in my company but have not a big knowledge of iOS Development. My boss would like to have an app which automatically disable or enable the wifi-calling function of his iPhone depends of the network he is currently connected to.

After a research I did not found any possiblity to change a device setting of the iPhone through the app. Is this correct or is there any possibility to change device settings automatically?

Thank you for your help!
Simon

Comment: There is no apple approved way of changing a system setting like that from a sandboxed iOS app. Probably there could be some MDM solution for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force an iOS app to use 3G instead of WiFi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925724/how-do-i-force-an-ios-app-to-use-3g-instead-of-wifi)