# LTE internet during WIFI connection?

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to programmatically force iphone to download LTE internet during WIFI connection?

I am connected via WIFI to a device with no internet connection. But I need to use MapKit (via LTE)

Best regards.

Comment: Do you mean to test some of your apps behaviors or do you want to force a user to do some networking tasks under only a certain network connection such as LTE in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I force an iOS app to use 3G instead of WiFi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925724/how-do-i-force-an-ios-app-to-use-3g-instead-of-wifi)

Comment: Im editing post.

Comment: I am connected via WIFI to a device with no internet connection. But I need to use MapKit (via LTE)